# Why the sign of eigenfunction of Laplacian operator is reversed?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, laplacian, eigenfunctions

I am newbie for math and linear algebra.
Now I am reading about eigenfunction of the Laplacian operator.

If I have $Ax=\lambda x$ ( Let's assume that A is matrix, x is vector, λ is scalar ), I know that x is eigenvector and λ is eigenvalue.

According to wikipedia( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenfunction ), if I have 'Df=λf'( D is linear operator and λ is scalar ), f is eigenfunction and λ is eigenvalue. It is very similar to eigenvector case, so it is okay to me.

However when I tried to search eigenfunction for Laplacian operator, they always say that f is eigenfunction and λ is eigenvalue for below equations! ( The sign is reversed! )

$$Δf=-λf \text { or } Δf+\lambda f=0$$

I really don't know why the sign is changed for Laplacian eigenfunction.
I found that above equations are known as Helmholtz equation. So is it just definition that 'eigenfunction of Laplace operator is f and eigenvalue is λ when we have Δf=-λf'? Or is there some derivation that I am missing?

Could you explain about this? Thanks!

Comment: Depending on your conventions the Laplacian is negative-definite so its eigenvalues will all be nonpositive, and you might want $\lambda$ to be nonnegative. It's just a convention, it doesn't change the mathematics. Solving this equation is equivalent to computing the eigenvalues of $-\Delta$.

Comment: What's already been said, with maybe a different emphasis: The operator $-\Delta$ is positive (semi-)definite, and positive definite operators are things we "understand", so it's natural to want to know about the eigenvalues of $-\Delta$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you very much for your answer! Could you explain more about why 'Laplacian is negative-definite'? I don't understand intuitively or mathematically.

Comment: See, for example, Theorem 3 here: https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220b/handouts/eigenvalues.pdf

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you for your help! That link is pretty hard to me, ;( But thank you again!